# How would I separate this with a Substring?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a flatfile that contains data like this: I'm trying to separate it out; however, I don't know how to find the first non int number in a SUBSTRING function. I'm profiling this data.

```
011000015O0110000150122415000000000FEDERAL RESERVE BANK
011001962O1210003742080312122203950CATHAY BANK
```

So far, I have separated the first 3 parts of this number sequence; however, I'm having trouble finding out a good way to separate the beginning of the Name of the Bank (FEDERAL RESEVE BANK). All of the rows in this flatfile have different char lengths.

Sometimes, tere are 9 zeros, 10 zeroes, and no repetitive zeros at all. For the profiling of this data, I don't need those zeros or consequent numbers.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1, 0,10) ROUTING_NUMBER,
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1,11,9) FEDRESERVE_NUM,
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1,20,7) NO_IDEA_YET,
    SUBSTRING(FIELD1,
FROM srcFlatFile.dbo.fedachdir2018
```

This is what I need (the "O" doesn't need it's own column and the '000000000' and '122203950' are not needed right now):

```
011000015 O 011000015 0122415 000000000 FEDERAL RESERVE BANK
011001962 O 121000374 2080312 122203950 CATHAY BANK
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields seem fixed length, so you can use:

```
select stuff(field, 1, 35, '')
```

You can also search for the bank name.  This is made rather complicated by the presence of Os in the name (as opposed to 0):

```
select stuff(field, 1, patindex('%[^0-9O]%', field) - 1, ''), patindex('%[^0-9O]%', field)
```

Comment: How would I find the length of the Bank Name since they are all different? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Lizzie . . . You can just take the length of this value.

Comment: Here let me add more information:

011000015O0110000150122415000000000FEDERAL RESERVE BANK                1000 PEACHTREE ST N.E.              ATLANTA             GA303094470877372245711     

is everything I'm looking at. How do I now find the length of the Bank name.

Once I learn this, I can do the rest :)
Your edit makes more sense, thank you

Comment: @Lizzie . . . That is actually different from the question you actually asked.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with more appropriate sample data and desired results.